# Printf gone wild

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

There is quite a lot of code in my source but the main problem is in 2 consecutive lines.

```
 struct step
 {
     int left,tonum;
     long long int rez;
 };

inline bool operator==(const step& a, const step& b)
{
    printf("\n%d",b.tonum);
    printf("\n%d %d | %d %d | %d %d",a.left, b.left, a.rez, b.rez, a.tonum, b.tonum);
    return a.left==b.left && a.rez==b.rez && a.tonum==b.tonum;
}
```

This gets called quite a few million times but the problem is that although it should be the same most of the time, it never is, and the output is very strange indeed.

```
2
7989 7989 | 53 0 | 53 0
1
8989 7989 | 52 0 | 53 0
2
8989 8989 | 52 0 | 52 0
1
7899 8989 | 51 0 | 52 0
```

Not only should `b.tonum` be the same but also he should be `== a.tonum` for some other reasons not explained in this piece of code

Why isnt `b.tonum` printed the same both times?

Comment: +1, just for the title.

Comment: How do _you_ know the problem is in those lines? Did you make a [testcase](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/) to prove it? Where is it?

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing those print statements to execute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use `%d` to print a `long long`. You'd have to use `%lld`. (So use `"\n%d %d | %lld %lld | %d %d"` for your format string.)

In particular, it's apparent that in the "52 0 | 52 0", the first 52 0 is `a.rez`, and the second 52 0 is `b.rez` (each of these, being a `long long`, is apparently (judging from the output) pushing two words to the stack). `a.tonum` and `b.tonum` are not printed at all.

---

To understand why this is happening, let me explain what Jonathan and I are trying to say. When you invoke a variadic function like `printf` (which is declared as something like `printf(const char *format, ...)`, the compiler has *no* way to validate the correct argument types for the `...` at compile-time. So there's a procedure for deciding what to push on the stack in that case, which can roughly be summarised as: if it's `int` or promotable to `int`, it gets pushed as an `int`; if it's `double` or promotable to `double`, it gets pushed as a `double`; otherwise, it gets pushed as is.

When implementing a variadic function like `printf`, you need some way to access the `...` items. The way to do so is to use a `va_list`, which is declared in `<stdarg.h>`. Here's some pseudocode which shows how it'd be used:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    while (/* we find the next format marker */) {
        if (/* %d, %i, %c */) {
            int val = va_arg(ap, int);
            /* print out val as decimal or (for %c) char */
        } else if (/* %u, %x, %X, %o */) {
            unsigned int val = va_arg(ap, unsigned int);
            /* print out val as decimal, hex, or octal */
        } else if (/* %ld, %li */) {
            long val = va_arg(ap, long);
            /* print out val as decimal */
        } else if (/* %lu, %lx, %lX, %lo */) {
            unsigned long val = va_arg(ap, unsigned long);
            /* print out val as decimal, hex, or octal */
        } else if (/* %lld, %lli */) {
            long long val = va_arg(ap, long long);
            /* print out val as decimal */
        } else if (/* %llu, %llx, %llX, %llo */) {
            unsigned long long val = va_arg(ap, unsigned long long);
            /* print out val as decimal, hex, or octal */
        } else if (/* %s */) {
            const char *val = va_arg(ap, const char *);
            /* print out val as null-terminated string */
        } /* other types */
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return /* ... */;
}
```

Notice that each time you want to pick off a `...` argument, you'd do so using `va_arg`, and you'd have to specify the type to pick off. It is up to you to pick off the correct type. If the type is incorrect, you have a type-punning situation, which in most cases has undefined behaviour (meaning that the program can do anything it likes, including crashing or worse).

In your particular computer, it seems like when you passed a `long long`, it pushed a 64-bit quantity to the stack, but because you used a `%d` format specifier, it used the `va_arg(ap, int)` version, which only grabbed a 32-bit quantity. That means that the other half of the 64-bit word was still unread, which the subsequent `%d` then proceeded to read. This is why, by the time the format string was finished, it never got around to processing the values of `a.tonum` and `b.tonum` that you passed.

Whereas, had you correctly used `%lld`, it would have used `va_arg(ap, long long)`, and would have correctly read in the whole 64-bit quantity.

Comment: Why use `printf` at all?

Comment: This hardly explains why `a.tonum` and `b.tonum` differ.

Comment: @chris:  Who knows.  Sometimes a hammer is the best tool for the job.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I edited my answer to explain why, but it's because they are not being printed at all. The passing of `a.rez` and `b.rez` is pushing two words to the stack each.

Comment: While possible (and I'll support you with a +1), to be precise you don't _know_ that. You don't know his platform, architecture, anything. That being said the pattern of output, when you compensate for this effect, matches his expectation. So you're probably on the money.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't _know_, but the output supports my anecdotal hypothesis.

Comment: @JohnDibling, But you could at least use a hammer that morphs into the perfect hammer for each nail instead of allowing yourself to choose the wrong one.

Comment: @chris Cuz speed brah.

Comment: Since the code invoked undefined behaviour, any output is valid. However, the output of 53 and 0 twice is consistent with two 8-byte `long long` values being pushed and read as four 4-byte values, and the values pushed as `a.tonum` and `b.tonum` are ignored.

Comment: @kungi "The faster you go, the bigger the mess." http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uV5o_-UADiY (That's one of the less graphic ones; go and search YouTube for more. New Zealand is really into the graphic ads to discourage drivers from speeding.)

Comment: I admit I also hate printf but since I'm writing algorithms I've been constantly encouraged to write printf since it's supposed huge speed advantage over cout

Comment: @kungi: std::cout Shouldn't be much slower than printf. The performance bottleneck lies somewhere else in IO. So the performance difference will probably be negligible.